# Cant Connect MSSQL server Using sqoop to Hadoop

Tags: sql-server, apache, hadoop, sqoop

I am trying to connect Mssql server to Hadoop using Sqoop.I cant able to connect to MSSQL server .I am struct on this for the past two days would anyone please help me to solve this problem .when I am trying list a databases in MSSQL server using Sqoop it will get error like this

```
Failed to list databases
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host 192.168.1.26, port 1433 has failed. Error: "connect timed out. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:191)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.ConvertConnectExceptionToSQLServerException(SQLServerException.java:242)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SocketFinder.findSocket(IOBuffer.java:2280)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.open(IOBuffer.java:493)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1387)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:1068)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:904)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:451)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1014)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:233)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.makeConnection(SqlManager.java:883)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.GenericJdbcManager.getConnection(GenericJdbcManager.java:52)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.CatalogQueryManager.listDatabases(CatalogQueryManager.java:57)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ListDatabasesTool.run(ListDatabasesTool.java:49)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:143)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:179)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:218)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:227)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:236)
16/07/27 16:35:24 ERROR sqoop.Sqoop: Got exception running Sqoop: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host 192.168.1.26, port 1433 has failed. Error: "connect timed out. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host 192.168.1.26, port 1433 has failed. Error: "connect timed out. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.CatalogQueryManager.listDatabases(CatalogQueryManager.java:73)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ListDatabasesTool.run(ListDatabasesTool.java:49)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:143)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:179)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:218)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:227)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:236)
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host 192.168.1.26, port 1433 has failed. Error: "connect timed out. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:191)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.ConvertConnectExceptionToSQLServerException(SQLServerException.java:242)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SocketFinder.findSocket(IOBuffer.java:2280)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.open(IOBuffer.java:493)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1387)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:1068)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:904)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:451)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1014)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:233)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.makeConnection(SqlManager.java:883)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.GenericJdbcManager.getConnection(GenericJdbcManager.java:52)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.CatalogQueryManager.listDatabases(CatalogQueryManager.java:57)
    ... 7 more
```

Comment: Could post your Sqoop command

Comment: is connectivity open between hadoop cluster nodes and MSSQL server? check connectivity from hadoop nodes: telnet 192.168.1.26 1433